# Does a queue make sense for multiprocessing even when you only expect a single result back?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to execute a function in another process and get a single result back (either true or false). I know [the common way of getting results back from multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329974/can-i-get-a-return-value-from-multiprocessing-process) is using a queue, but does it make sense if I only expect a single result back?

```
p = Process(target=my_function_that_returns_boolean, args=(self, args))
p.start()
p.join()
# success = p.somehow_get_the_result_back
```

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to use `Process` rather than `Pool`, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) tells us that there are two ways to exchange objects between processes.

The first is `Queue` which you have already seen.

The second is `Pipe`, which the documentation provides an example for. I have slightly modified the example to show your case of returning a boolean.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe


def Foo(conn):
  # Do necessary processing here
  # ....
  # Instead of Return True, we send true
  #return True
  conn.send(True)


parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
p = Process(target=Foo, args=(child_conn,))
p.start()
print parent_conn.recv()
p.join()
```

Comment: `Pipe` is faster than `Queue`, for what it's worth. It won't make any noticeable difference if you're only returning a single object, though.

Answer (score 1):

Queues are used to synchronize access to shared resources in a parallel environment. Common scenarios are when many workers consume tasks from a shared pool or when one execution line creates tasks and another consumes them.

If I understand correctly, it isn't an issue here. So there is no need to use queues. The only synchronization mechanism you need is one that tells one process that the other is done. This is achieved by using `join()`.

Unless there is a real problem just keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: But join doesn't return anything, how do I get the result back?

Comment: @merlin2011, I only see `result_queue.get()`, I must be blind. Where is the object with a `get()` method?

Comment: @Clash You're not missing anything, there is no `get` to call when you use a `Process`. You should use a `Queue` or `Pipe` to get the result back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Pool` which returns an [AsyncResult](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) object

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool(processes=1)              
result = pool.apply_async(my_function_that_returns_boolean, [(self, args),])    
success = result.get(timeout=None)
```